# Where can I get equivalent of 3 months libor or swap historical data?

Tags: interest-rates, historical-data

Please note: I have already checked your standard "Historical data sources" link, but it does not have the data I need:

I am looking for 5 years of libor/swap data for major currencies. Daily, or even better hourly.

Is this available anywhere?

An example of what I would like is: Bloomberg  ADSW2 CMPL Curncy.

Is there a free equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

This site might be useful http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/pages/yieldcurve/default.aspx. It has the nominal 3 mo LIBOR swap rates

Answer (score 1):

This [site](http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/libor.aspx) used to be a good free source. I'd be surprised if you find a good source with daily LIBOR rates for major currencies with easy automatic download.

Answer (score 1):

Does the link below help? It's free and has daily 3 month rates.

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/search?st=Libor+3+month+daily

Answer (score 1):

Download this application. It provides free LIBOR and Swap historical data covering 3 months, OIS and basis for all major currencies. https://finpricing.com/download.html
[image: list of libor and swap cuves in FinPricign]